# C# Winforms anchoring doesn't work when started maximized

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have windows form with some form with buttons and other components. Buttons are anchored to **Bottom** and **Right**. When the application is started as maximized, the buttons don't appear in the corner of the form as they should but remain as if they were anchored to **Top** and **Left**. If I unmaximize this form, they remain as far away from the bottom right as in maximized. However, if the form is started *normal*, not maximized, then everything is ok and the buttons are in the corner. I have the same buttons in other forms and there everything works good, only this one is broken. How can I fix this?

Designer:

[image: designer]

Form started maximized:

[image: maximized]

Form unmaximized:

[image: unmaximized]

Now I change the WindowState from Maximized to Normal:

[image: normal unmaximized]

And when I maximize:

[image: normal maximized]

And this happens only in this form, in other forms, this solution works fine, it doesn't matter if maximized or normal. What is broken in this particular form?

Designer.cs code for this form is the following (the whole file has over 600 lines, so I selected the important ones:

```cs
            this.buttonAneks = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
(...)

            // buttonAneks
            // 
            this.buttonAneks.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.buttonAneks.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
            this.buttonAneks.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.buttonAneks.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(715, 585);
            this.buttonAneks.Name = "buttonAneks";
            this.buttonAneks.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.buttonAneks.TabIndex = 103;
            this.buttonAneks.Text = "Aneksy";
            this.buttonAneks.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.buttonAneks.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAneks_Click);
(...)
            this.Controls.Add(this.buttonAneks);
            this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.buttonAneks, 0);
(...)
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonAneks;
```

Comment: Do you set anchoring from your own code or do you just use the designer?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I have set it in the designer

Comment: What is the parent of the buttons?  From the behaviour we see in your your screen shots it would appear to be the panel with the vertical scroll bar rather than the form itself.  Have a look in the designer.cs file.  Add the buttons to the form's controls, not the panel's controls.

Comment: @Mark the parent of the buttons is the form itself, and the panel with scrollbar was added later.

Comment: @TK-421 Can you paste the form's designer.cs code here so we can read it.  Anchoring works, (even for maximised forms) so logically it's your code that has an issue.

Comment: @Mark I have added the code, however, I don't know why this behavior changes when changing the WindowState property...

Comment: @TK-421   I can't see anything wrong there.  If all the other forms are working correctly I would suggest either comparing the designer.cs with a working one on a line by line basis, or else recreating the form from scratch.  If you do the latter add the buttons first and check their behaviour after each new addition...    Sorry, I have no other suggestions.  Let us know how you get on...

Comment: I think you're missing something about a panel or something that contains the buttons. look over that again maybe u found something.

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani As I said, the buttons are not inside the panel, and the panel was added later and it also is not positioned correctly

Comment: So that items and their attributes should be debugged line by line to see what's the problem.

Comment: @MohamadShahrestani If there was a problem I could find by looking at it line by line, then I wouldn't be asking here for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was the Adobe PDF Reader control axAcroPDF, which was present in this particular form, and for unknown reasons, it caused such behavior. Removing it solved the problem.